# Read a file and generate a list of lists using list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'd like to read a file with the following input:

```
10
20
30

50
60
70

80
90
100
```

and generate the following output:

```
[['10', '20', '30'], ['50','60','70'] ... ]
```

using list comprehensions and not foor loops. Naturally the problem I'm facing is creating the nested list when a `\n` character is detected. Of course 'disclaimer' the code would probably be more readable with for loops!

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line != '\n']

print(result)

//
```

```
['10', '20', '30', '50', '60', '70']
// not correct
```

Comment: Added a second duplicate link, in case the question is intended to be specifically about the mechanics of the list comprehension. The material is well covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `split` (so, different from the solutions you are exploring with comprehensions).

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [s.split("\n") for s in f.read().split("\n\n")]
print(result)
```

This other approach uses the functional-programming tools,  comprehension and  `groupby`, and so is more in the spirit of what you asked for.

```py
from itertools import groupby

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [[s.strip() for s in group] for key, group in groupby(f, lambda x: x == "\n") if not key]
print(result)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy it splits a multiline string into lines. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you @KellyBundy! I did not know that you could read a file directly that way. Also, I added the `import` statement.

Comment: Oh right, I wanted to complain about that but forgot :-)